# How to use react-hook-form inside class Component?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-component, react-hook-form

I use the following code to create a login page with form validation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  
const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
console.log(errors);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

            <Label>Email : </Label>
            <Input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" ref={register({required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})}></Input>

            <Label>Password : </Label>
            <Input type="password" placeholder="password"  name="password" ref={register({required: true, min: 8, maxLength: 20})}></Input>

        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default SignIn;
```

and I have a problem using react-hook-form inside the Class Component

My question, if it's possible, is: How to use the react-hook-form with Class Component without rewriting the code to the hook version?

Comment: If you still have the problem look at my answer, I even added a live sandbox!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easiest way will be to change class Component, to a functional Component and use the useForm hook. Below you can find the example code:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const SignIn = () => {

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

        <Label>Email : </Label>
        <Input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" ref={register({required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})}></Input>

        <Label>Password : </Label>
        <Input type="password" placeholder="password"  name="password" ref={register({required: true, min: 8, maxLength: 20})}></Input>

        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  )}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Not a good idea. Sometimes we need to use components due to their events!

Comment: In fact this a big reason in my side to expect something will replace React (not Angular nor Vue). I was already working with dozens of examples to understand React and someday I hit the wall of "you cannot use this in a class component". For me, a class component is really useful in terms of abstraction and hierarchies. For example, I manage diferent implementations using polymorphism. I have seen auth implementations that could be easier using inheritance of a Route component, but most examples rewrite it in a function, which for me smells like a bad practice

Answer (score 7):

You can't use hooks in react class components.
The class that you provide looks small and I think that you can easily rewrite it to functional component. Perhaps you don't want to, you can provide hoc with useForm hook that wraps your class component.

```
export const withUseFormHook = (Component) => {
    return props => {
        const form = useForm();
        return <Component {...props} {...form} />
    }       
}
```

And in you SignIn component simply do:

```
export default withUseFormHook(SignIn);
```

Comment: I am just a beginner with React.js, your answer looks like something new for me

Comment: But I think that it's similar to my answer. my answer is creating a hook Component and use it inside the Class Component, and your answer is the reverse. that's it?

Comment: Not really, in your answer you created new functional Component that can replace class Component. I will comment your answer with a little bit more simple solution than yours.

Comment: I used somethin called Higher Order Component, its a bit more advanced React pattern, but if you want just read about it, and it's usage in an official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns

Comment: @piotrruss Thanks, based on your answer I could solve my issue.

Comment: this is not working for me, after creating this component inside the SignIn component I am not getting the form values or any prop values. Please tell me how can I access the props and form values inside SignIn component.
Also, inside HOC it shows an error for useForm();
React Hook "useForm" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

Comment: Please add a working example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the react-hook-form documentation:

> Does it work with Class Components?
>
> No, not out of the box. If you wanted to do this, you could build a
> wrapper around it and use it in your Class Component.

https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#DoesitworkwithClassComponents

Answer (score 1):

After searching more and more I used this solution :

Creating a separate file with the hook version :

```
import React from 'react'

import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const SignInHook = () => {

    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
    console.log(errors);



    return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

            <Label>Email : </Label>
            <Input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" ref={register({required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})}></Input>

            <Label>Password : </Label>
            <Input type="password" placeholder="password"  name="password" ref={register({required: true, min: 8, maxLength: 20})}></Input>

        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
   )
}

export default SignInHook
```

And Use it inside my Class Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import SignInHook from './SignInHook';

class SignIn extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SignInHook></SignInHook>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default SignIn;
```

Comment: You can totally remove SignIn component and change SignInHook -> SignIn, update import path wherever you import SignIn and it will work ;)

Comment: I am still sticking to the Class method that’s why. I will try to use your solution also.

Comment: I see your edit. I suggest to use it as a new answer. It's better to have a question with more than one useful answer.

Comment: I am new here so I don't know a lot about the rules. If it's good to use your edit as a new answer then it's okay, if not I will approve your edit.

Comment: I was a little bit lazy :P I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but at the end I could solve it like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <label>Example</label>
        <input name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
        <label>ExampleRequired</label>
        <input
          name="exampleRequired"
          ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 10 })}
        />
        {errors.exampleRequired && <p>This field is required</p>}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function App(props) {
  const form = useForm();
  return <Login {...props} {...form} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-xz5np?file=/src/index.js:0-1815) is the live sandbox.

Comment: I have opened an issue but at the end in a discussion the solution discovered:
https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/4258

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code it works:

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
...
  render() {
    const {
      register,
      formState: { errors },
      handleSubmit } = (() => useForm({ mode: "onChange" }))();
    return (...);
  }
}
```

is it a good practice do it?