# How to use React Hook Form with class based component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have checked the official doc and realised we cannot directly use Hooks inside the class-based component. So, I have tried the HOC method to use react-hook-form with a class-based component.

But this case is also not working in my case.

My HOC Component::

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

export const ClassHookFormWrap = (Component) => {
   const form = useForm();
   console.log("form", form, Component)
   return (props) => {
      return <Component form={form} {...props}  />;
   };
};
```

My class-based component::

```
import React from "react";
import { ClassHookFormWrap } from "./ClassHookFormWrap";

class ClassHookForm extends React.Component {
   onSubmit = (data) => {
      console.log(data);
   }
   render(){
      console.log("this.props", this.props)
      return(
         <div>Form</div>
      )
   }
}

export default ClassHookFormWrap(ClassHookForm);
```

The error I got inside console::

[image]

This is a sandbox link I have added a code sample here:: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-monad-7mkxg8?file=/src/App.js:224-237

Is there any way to use this form inside a class-based component?

Comment: Why are you still using class components in 2022? They are legacy in React

Comment: Avoid use hooks in Class Components, Update your projects with functional components if you really want to use Hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, hooks have to be used inside the body of the functional component. you are using it inside the HOC and HOC is a function, not a functional component, but what HOC returns is a component (here functional component). So **just move the useForm inside return,** instead of directly using it inside HOC. something like this.

```
   export const ClassHookFormWrap = (Component) => {
   return (props) => {
   const form = useForm();
   console.log("form", form, Component)
      return <Component form={form} {...props}  />;
   };
};
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Add the returning component a name to avoid eslint error.

```
export const ClassHookFormWrap = (Component) => {
  return function Wrap(props) {
    const form = useForm();
    console.log("form", form, Component);
    return <Component form={form} {...props} />;
  };
};
```

Comment: Its not working, I already tried this before. It gives me compile time error:: Line 8:20:  React Hook "useForm" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: yeah, try to give the return Component a name.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are supposed to be used inside a component or inside a custom hook. A HOC is basically a function which returns a component. So in order to get this working you can move the useForm hook into the return function like this

```
export const ClassHookFormWrap = (Component) => {
   return (props) => {
      const form = useForm();
      console.log("form", form, Component)
      return <Component form={form} {...props}  />;
   };
};
```

Comment: ha ha.. we answered at the same time :)

Comment: ha ha :D ... technically not the same time though, beat you by a minute ;)

Comment: I am getting this error if moving useForm inside return function::      ` Line 8:20:  React Hook "useForm" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`

Comment: If you are looking for a way to move your useForm logic into a wrapper component, you can just go ahead and create a normal functional component containing the useForm logic (basically a wrapper component) and then passing the component which needs this logic as a prop or as its child.

Comment: You can also refer to this related SO thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291330/how-to-use-react-hook-form-inside-class-component

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way will be to change class Component, to a functional Component and use the useForm hook.

And Still You want same i used like this (Note: this is my example you can change it as per your requirment):

Seprate File for hook version:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const SignInHook = () => {

const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
console.log(errors);

return (
<>
  <div>
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

        <Label>Email : </Label>
        <Input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" ref={register({required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})}></Input>

        <Label>Password : </Label>
        <Input type="password" placeholder="password"  name="password" ref={register({required: true, min: 8, maxLength: 20})}></Input>

    </Form>
  </div>
</>
)
}

export default SignInHook
```

And Use it inside my Class Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import SignInHook from './SignInHook';

class SignIn extends React.Component {

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <SignInHook></SignInHook>
  </div>
);
}}

export default SignIn;
```